# onNavigationItemSelected is not working on Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, events, navigation-drawer

I'm trying to get click event of Navigation Drawer item.
What I did is as below.

(1) Create a new Android source project selecting 'Navigation Drawer Activity' on 'Select a Project Template'. (Min SDK : API 22 - Lollipop)

(2) Add one item on '/res/menu/activity_main_drawer.xml'.

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
        android:title="@string/menu_home" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        android:title="@string/menu_gallery" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
        android:title="@string/menu_slideshow" />
</group>

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_notification"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
    android:title="Notification" />
```

(3) MainActivity implements NavigationItemSelectedListener, and define event function - onNavigationItemSelected()

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

```
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.menu_notification) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Menu - Notification", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    return true;
}
```

(4) Set NavigationItemSelectedListener to MainActivity in onCreate() method.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
    DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.bringToFront();
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
            R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow)
            .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
            .build();
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this,
        R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
}
```

This is all I did. After run this application on Emulator, I clicked new menu item (Notification), but nothing happened.
onNavigationItemSelected() can not get event of item click.

What I have to do to get click event of Navigation Drawer item?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this doesn't work is because you are using **Navigation Component**. If you want `onNavigationItemSelected` method to be called, remove the mentioned line below:

```
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
```

After that, keep in mind that you should manage selected items manually as **Navigation** won't do it for you anymore.